# How do I pass the last question of the book puzzle in the second Gym on Pokemon Black?

Tags: pokemon-black-white

I started playing Pokemon Black on my PC using Desmume, but, for some reason, on the second gym, I can't pass the book puzzle.

On the very last question of the puzzle, I go to the middle right bookshelf and talk to the girl on the ladder. In every video I watch, talking to her triggers a question, and answering "yes" makes you battle her. Though, for some reason, even though I answered every other question, talking to her doesn't trigger that question.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: What source are you using for the actual game? This could be an issue with the particular game on the emulator.